# match key and insert into new column

Tags: python, sqlite, dictionary

I got a bunch of Python dicts and need to organize these into an SQLite database. The dicts use Unix timestamps as key and then a value. The dicts currently looks like this:

```
{1487462400: u'385', 1481932800: u'270', 1464393600: u'213', 1459814400: u'780'}
```

I can convert these to a list or tuple and just insert the keys and values into an SQLite table but what I need to do is then take a new list, match the Unix timestamp keys, and insert the new values in a new column. Can I use `executemany` and automatically match the keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the table already has the new column, to write a single value, you would use a statement like this:

```sql
UPDATE MyTable SET NewColumn = ? WHERE TimeStamp = ?;
```

You can use this with `executemany()` if the parameter array has this form:

```
[('new value', 1487462400), ('hello', 1481932800), ('xxx', 1464393600), ('...', 1459814400)]
```

If you prefer to have the timestamp first (as returned by `mydict.items()`), you can specify [parameter numbers](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam):

```sql
UPDATE MyTable SET NewColumn = ?2 WHERE TimeStamp = ?1;
```

Comment: Cool! I'm going to try it out but seems like what I want to do. Didn't know about the parameter numbers. Great stuff :)

Comment: Is there any way to create a column if not exist in sqlite?